# How to reset DropDownList to it's initial value/option

Tags: c#, html, html-select, blazor-server-side, reset

I want to be able to click on a button to reset the DropDownList to its initial value. In this example a role is to be selected. The initial role is ID 1 (Normal Role). How do I force the DropDownList to rebuild? I am not using javascript just c# and blazor.

```
@page "/"

<h3>DropDownList - ComboBox</h3>

<form>
    <select class="form-control col-6" @onchange="@(x => OnSelChange(x.Value.ToString()))">
        <option value="" disabled>--SelectName--</option>
        @foreach (var role in roleList)
        {
            @if (role.RoleId == myroleID)
            {
                <option value=@role.RoleId selected>@role.Name</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value=@role.RoleId>@role.Name</option>
            }

        }
    </select>

    @if (SelectedRole != null)
    {
        <p>Sel Role-Obj.Name: @SelectedRole.Name @SelectedRole.RoleId</p>
    }

    <button type="button" @onclick="@Reset">Reset DropDownList to initial value</button>

</form>




@code {
    public Role SelectedRole;
    public List<Role> roleList = new List<Role>();
    public int myroleID;

    public class Role
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Role(string name, int id)
        {
            RoleId = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
        

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Role normal = new Role("Normal",1);
        roleList.Add(normal);

        Role Admin = new Role("Admin",2);
        roleList.Add(Admin);

        Role Super = new Role("Super",3);
        roleList.Add(Super);

        myroleID = 1;
    }

    public void OnSelChange(string role)
    {
        SelectedRole = roleList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RoleId.ToString() == role);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
       
    }   
}
```

I have tried implementing a variable that is initilised at the start but I'm not sure what else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to start with a default value, you don't need the dummy with `disabled`.  It is only there to provide a visual cue.

Second, given that you already check against the ID in building your `<option>` set, I think you can just set your ID:

`public int myRoleID = 1;`

```
public void Reset(){
    myRoleID = 1;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you are likely to want to use the same or similar select several times in your application.

I overcome the *default* by defining a default Role.

```cs
@page "/"

<h3>DropDownList - ComboBox</h3>

<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-3">
            <BlazrInputSelect class="form-select"
                              @bind-Value:get=SelectedRole.RoleId
                              @bind-Value:set=this.OnRoleChanged
                              DisplayOptionsItems=roleList
                              OptionTextDelegate="(role) => role.Name"
                              OptionValueDelegate="(role) => role.RoleId.ToString()" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @onclick=this.Reset>Reset DropDownList to initial value</button>
</form>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-1">
    <pre>Selected Role: @SelectedRole.Name</pre>
    <pre>Selected Role Id: @SelectedRole.RoleId</pre>
</div>




@code {
    private static Role DefaultRole = new("Normal", 1);

    public Role SelectedRole = DefaultRole;

    public List<Role> roleList = new()
    {
        new("Normal", 1),
        new("Admin", 2),
        new("Super", 3),
    };

    public void OnRoleChanged(int roleId)
        => SelectedRole = roleList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.RoleId == roleId) ?? DefaultRole;


    public void Reset()
        => SelectedRole = DefaultRole;

    public class Role
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Role(string name, int id)
        {
            RoleId = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

And `BlazrIputSelect`

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@typeparam TValue
@typeparam TListItem

<InputSelect @attributes=AdditionalAttributes
             TValue="TValue"
             Value=this.Value
             ValueChanged=this.OnChange
             ValueExpression=this.ValueExpression>

    @if (this.Value is null)
    {
        <option selected disabled>@this.PlaceholderText</option>
    }

    @foreach (var option in this.DisplayOptionsItems)
    {
        <option value="@(this.OptionValueDelegate(option))">@(this.OptionTextDelegate(option))</option>
    }

</InputSelect>

@code {
    [Parameter] public TValue? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<TValue>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<TListItem> DisplayOptionsItems { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, string> OptionValueDelegate { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, string> OptionTextDelegate { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public string PlaceholderText { get; set; } = " -- Select an Option -- ";
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Check we have a Options list if not throw an exception before we try and render a null list
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.DisplayOptionsItems);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.OptionValueDelegate);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.OptionTextDelegate);
    }

    private Task OnChange(TValue value)
        => this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
}
```